# New Lead alert not been sent from Email Service

Tags: apex-email-service, email2lead

When creating a Lead through the UI, the system is sending a New Lead Alert to the New lead owner.

However, I discovered, that if using Email Services - that New Lead alert is **NOT** been sent.

- Anyone knows if this is a bug or by design?
- Do I need to update my Email service?

Here is the relevant class.

- Is the automated respons needs to go by: the `insert lead` line?
- or the fact that I have set the `lead.OwnerId` actually disables the assignment rules I have?

  ```
  try{
  mToAddressBefore = envelope.toAddress.subString(0,envelope.toAddress.indexOf('@'));
  mParams = mToAddressBefore.split('\\.');
  mFromEmail = email.fromAddress; 
  // Get the user id
  User u1 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Alias = :mParams[1]];

  mCaseObject = mParams[0];
   if (mCaseObject == 'lead'){
      lead = new Lead();
      lead.LastName = mFromEmail.subString(0,mFromEmail.indexOf('@'));
      lead.Company = mFromEmail;
      lead.OwnerId = u1.Id;
      lead.LeadSource = mParams[2];
      lead.Email = mFromEmail;
      lead.RequirementsDescription__c = email.subject + '\\n' + email.plainTextBody;

      insert lead;
      result.success = true;
  }  else if (mCaseObject == 'case'){
    result.success = true;
  }  else {
    result.success = false;
  }
    }catch(Exception e){
  //   result.success = false;
  //   result.message = 'Oops, I failed. **' + mFromEmail + '**' + mParams[1] + '**' + sourcetext + '**';
  }
  return result;
  ```

The leads are assigned correctly ( I set the owner within the email lead name - u1.Id)

The problem is that the email notification is not sent, again, this is only when the email service is used. Not when doing a regular new lead creation using the UI.

Comment: Is the problem that it is not being assigned properly, or that the email isn't being sent? Or both?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Database DMLOptions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm).

Answer (score 7):

I think you might need to set the DMLOptions to trigger autoresponse email. So something like this:

```
Id assignRuleId = [select Id from AssignmentRule where Name = ...].Id;

Database.DMLOptions dlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dlo.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId = assignRuleId; //specify assignment rule to tigger
//dlo.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = true; //this triggers lead queue assignment emails
Lead myLead = new Lead(...set field values here...);
database.insert(myLead, dlo);
```

Typically, I think you'd most likely use the assignment rule. The autoresponse header is typically only for when you manually assign a queue according to the docs. I don't think you would do both, as the assignment rule should trigger the Lead notification email anyway.

Comment: In my testing, I found that you need to use triggerUserEmail to get emails sent to the Assignee. I posted a different answer even though I'm using the same ideas.

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly tell it to use assignment rules and to send the emails using the [Database.DMLOptions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm).

```
Lead l = new Lead(FirstName = 'Joe', LastName = 'Smith', Company = 'XYZ Co');
Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
dmo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
Database.insert (l, dmo);
```

You may not need to do the assignment rule option since you are setting the owner in your code, but setting the email header option should have it send the email.